# Dynamic dictionary access

Tags: python, dictionary

related to dictionary and i want to access info from supermarket dynamically and if i access
in sequence  all thing perfectly printed  but if i want random access on items like wanted to
access soap in store1 is in or not then else part printed that 'item is not there'.

```
#dictionary to access data
supermarket={'store1':{'name':'vik general store','items':[{'name':'park avenue', 
            'quantity':200},{'name':'nivea','quantity':100}, {'name':'soap','quantity':500}]} 
            ,'store2':{'name':'lucky general store','items':[{'name':'salt','quantity':600}, 
            {'name':'sugar','quantity':700},{'name':'oil', 'quantity':400}]}}

##taking user input to enter store
s=input('enter the store name:') 

#if store 1 opted and then get data from supermarket
if s=='store1':
    ##every key in item will be considered in sequence
    for key in supermarket['store1']['items']:
        n=input('enter the product to find:')
        if key['name']==n:
            print('product detail is :',key['name'],'....',key['quantity'])
        else:
            print('item is not there')

#if store 2 opted and then get data from supermarket
elif s=='store2':
    #every key in item will be considered in sequence
    for key in supermarket['store2']['items']:
        n=input('enter the product to find:')
        if key['name']==n:
            print('product detail is :',key['name'],'....',key['quantity'])
        else:
            print('item is not there')
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it looks like the code for each "store" is identical, so just use `supermarket[s]`.  You can add `if s not in supermarket:...` and do something for an unknown "store".

Answer (score 0):

Op wants random access instead of sequential access, so I replaced the array named items from op's code with a dictionary with key as the product name and value as the quantity.

Then in the nested if statement I check if the product is present using special `__contains__()` method which returns a `bool` representing the presence of product and print the result

```
#dictionary to access data
supermarket = {
                'store1': { 
                            'name':'vik general store',
                            'items': { 'park avenue':200, 'nivea':100, 'soap':500 }
                        },
                'store2': {
                            'name':'lucky general store',
                            'items':{ 'salt':600, 'sugar':700, 'oil':400 }
                        }     
            }

##taking user input to enter store
s = input('enter the store name:') 

#if store 1 opted and then get data from supermarket
if s == 'store1':
    n=input('enter the product to find:')
    if supermarket['store1']['items'].__contains__(n):
        print('product detail is :',n,'....',supermarket['store1']['items'][n])
    else:
        print('item is not there')

#if store 2 opted and then get data from supermarket
elif s=='store2':
    n=input('enter the product to find:')
    if supermarket['store2']['items'].__contains__(n):
        print('product detail is :',n,'....',supermarket['store1']['items'][n])
    else:
        print('item is not there')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.